# Is there a way I can select from SQL and also select from Oracle and display in datagrid?

Tags: sql, vb.net, oracle

I am writing a program using VB, I can successfully pull data from SQL to a data grid separately, I also have an Oracle database that I can select data from too and display in a data grid.

This works fine when I do them independently. But is there a way I can select from SQL and also select from oracle and display them on a datagrid?

In other words, I have a database in SQL Server called A, and I have an Oracle database called B. I have a program that when I click a button I select [column name] from A. and when I also click on another button I select [column names] from database B.

My question is: I want to be able to create another button that would merge the results I have in A with the results I have in B and display the combined record in a datagrid. Kind of how a union works in SQL Server, but the columns have to be same, is there a way I can do something like that with 2 different databases from SQL Server and Oracle?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you say 'select from sql', do you mean select from Microsoft  SQL Server?  'sql' is a query language, but often people don't make the distinction between that and the MS database product.

Comment: Oracle also uses **SQL** as its query language - therefore your question is really too vague and more precise enough - what exactly do you mean by *pull data from SQL* ?? SQL is a **query language** used by almost all RDBMS - you cannot "pull data" from SQL - you can pull data **using** SQL - from any of the relevant RDBMS on the market....

Comment: My bad, I have a database on SSMS called A, I have another oracle databse called B. I have a program that when I click a button I selcect [colomn name] from A. and when I also click on another button I select [colomn names] from database B. My Question is I want to be able to create another button that would merge the results I have in A with the results I have in B and display the combined record in a datagrid. Kind of how a union works in MS SQL but the colomns has to be same, is there a way I can do something like that with 2 different databases from MS SQL and Oracle?

Comment: Please **edit your question** to improve it or add more details.

Comment: I have just edited it. Thanks

Comment: Even though you still mixing up your terminology a little, you have pretty much answered your own question.  your third button you've described could preform the query against the SQL Server DB and the Oracle DB, then you merge the results.  you can not query two separate DBMS systems in a single step.  Different connections, sometimes different sql syntax implementations etc